# python argparse: 'Namespace' error

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to build a process with some parsing option, some mandatory and others optinal.
I have a problem with the following code:

```
    bandlist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    process=['rad', 'ref', 'radref']
    sensors=['LC', 'LO', 'LE', 'LT']
    series=['4', '5', '7', '8']
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] "
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage)

    parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', dest='directory', action='store', type=str, \
                      help='complete path of landsat product folder: mydir/filename/')

    parser.add_argument('-p', '--process', dest='operation', action='store', choices = process, \
                      help='process requested: radiance, reflectance, both', default='rad')

    parser.add_argument('-l', '--series', dest='satellite', action='store', choices = series , \
                      help='Landsat series:4, 5, 7, 8')

    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sensor', dest='sensor', action='store', choices = sensors, \
                      help='sensor acronymous, for example LO for Landsat OLI, or LE for Landsat ETM+, etc..', default=None)

    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output',   dest='output', type=str, \
            help='Directory of output raster. \n \
                Unless specified, output directory will be workDirectory/results/datafolder/. \n \
                If specified, the output directory wil be mydirectory/results/filename/rad (and/or ref)/', default=None)

    parser.add_argument('-x', action='store_true', dest='bool', help='activate iterative radiance and/or reflectance computation for all the bands', default=False)

    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bands', dest='bands', choices = bandlist, type=int, \
                      help='bands to process', nargs='*', default=None)

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

and there is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract\LandsatTMroutine_RadiometricCorrection_1.0.py", line 1210, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\lbernardi\Desktop\extract\LandsatTMroutine_RadiometricCorrection_1.0.py", line 784, in main
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable
```

I don't understand what the error is about.
Thank for your help

Comment: `(options, args) =` is the `optparse` way.  `argparse` returns both types of arguments in one `Namespace` object.

Comment: Since you are moving from `optparse` to `argparse` (as seen in your previous question), you may need to study the last section of the `argparse` docs in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

`parse_args` doesn't return two items, it returns one.

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was issued by the interpreter while performing the `(options, args) = ...` assignment.  The parser returned one object, a `argparse.Namespace`.  But the assignment tries to split it into two items, e.g.

```
(options, args) = (args[0], args[1])
```

But the `Namespace` class definition does not implement a list or tuple like iteration.  A custom Namespace class could, in theory, do so.

That's the technical detail behind the error.  The practical issue is that `argparse` differs from `optparse`.

From the end of the `argparse` docs:

> Replace (options, args) = parser.parse_args() with args = parser.parse_args() and add additional ArgumentParser.add_argument() calls for the positional arguments. Keep in mind that what was previously called options, now in argparse context is called args.

`optparse` processes all the flagged strings, and puts their values in an `options` object (I forget its exact nature).  Strings that it can't process are returned as a list as the 2nd return value.

`argparse` expects you to define all arguments, both the flagged ones (called 'optionals') and unflagged ones (called 'positionals').  So values that in `optparse` would appear in the `args` list, appear under their own 'name/dest' in the `argparse` `namespace`.

There is another way of calling the argparse parser, `parser.parse_known_args` that behaves more like `optparse`.  Strings it can't handle are returned in an `extras` list.

You mention that some of your arguments are required and some are not.  At a first glance, your code makes everything 'optional'.  That is, if you don't include the relevant flag in the commandline, that argument will get its default value.

One of your arguments uses `nargs='*'`.  If that isn't specified the default will be `None` or `[]` (I forget the details).

You can also specify `required=True` parameter which makes an 'optional' required.  Sorry about the confusing terminology.  In that case, the parser will raise an error if you don't supply the flag in the commandline.

I didn't look much at your previous `optparse` question to see whether you expected an values in the `args` variable.  In `argparse` usage those are 'positionals' and are required (unless their `nargs` makes them 'optional').

So while the simple fix is just use `args = parser.parse_args()`, I suspect there's more under the surface.

A style point:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', dest='directory', action='store', type=str, \
                  help='complete path of t product folder: mydir/filename/')
```

can be simplified to

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--directory', \
                  help='complete path of landsat product folder: mydir/filename/')
```

If not given `dest` is infered from the first long flag string.  `store` is the default `action` value, and `str` is the default `type`.

In `argparse`, `type` is a function, one that converts the input string to something else.  `int` and `float` are the most common alternatives.  `str` works because it does nothing - returns the same string it was given. `argparse` actually uses an identify lambda function as the default `type` (e.g. `lambda x:x`).